# Main thread resumes execution after pthread_join even when the target thread is running

Tags: c++, multithreading, solaris

We are facing very strange issue in one of the customer environment. The Main thread launches a target pthread and then waits at pthread_join. We then run our traffic which is being handled by target thread but after few minutes we find main thread resuming execution after pthread_join. The target thread hasn't finished and is still up and running. This is running on Solaris9 Sparc and we have verified the threads using ps -eLf command that the target thread is up.

Can anyone please help if they have seen such a behavior with POSIX threads on Solaris9 Sparc.

```
extern "C" void *launchSmtpThread(void *idp)
{
   SmtpServerArg *serverArg = (SmtpServerArg*) idp;
   int rc = startSmtpServer(serverArg);
   cout <<"***********ERRORCODE from SMTP =="<<rc<<endl;
   return NULL;
}

-------------------
 ------------------
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

   ----------------------
   ----------------------
   smtpserverArg.config = &smtpConfig;
   smtpserverArg.appAlocFn = &createSmtpApp;

   pthread_t tid;
   pthread_create(&tid, NULL, launchSmtpThread, (void *)&smtpserverArg);

    -----------------
    ----------------- 

   //*****************************
   //wait on SmtpServer thread
   //*****************************
   int status;
   pthread_join(tid,(void**)&status);

   cout<< "exiting main()"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You are ignoring the return value of `pthread_join()`. Can you capture it, and print it out?

Comment: Thank aix..the return value of pthread_join is always 0.

Comment: The thread library on Solaris is pretty mature and it would be pretty surprising if it were so fundamentally broken. It is possible that the cerr output is being buffered so you are not actually noticing that the thread has in fact exited. You can test this by wrapping the launchSmtpThread in something that sets a global, and have your code after the pthread_join check the global. Alternatively, a remote possibility is that something is actually changing the thread status to detachable via pthread_detach.

Comment: It is also possible that the thread did not actually start (you need to check the return value of pthread_create as well).

Comment: What you are describing sounds pretty unlikely, so I suspect what actually happens isn't what you think happens. Could you produce a simple complete example that demonstrates this behaviour?

Comment: EmeryBerger, Before putting this post, we actually did what you suggested.  We decided to wait on a state of global variable after pthread_join. After putting that change, the process does not exit and the target thread keeps running and the process is working fine. Thereafter, I thought I will check with community if someone has faced similar issue below. There's another strange thing that happens which is the problem comes when the build is compiled with compiler option like "CC_FLGS+= -fast". The problem does not come in non-optimized build. Not sure how is this related.

Comment: If the thread does not make any function calls and its results do not propagate out as return values or globally-visible side effects, then the code could be optimized away... You can check by adding volatile to one of the modified values (which will prevent it being optimized away).